# CPU usage keep raising in VPS because of a Php script as an Uberlike

Tags: php, mysql, performance, api, rest

We have developed an Uber-like app, and recently we are facing some issues with the CPU usage.
Where during the day many users connect using the mobile application to a REST API end posting so many requests at one time.

But the CPU usage keeps raising every 5 minitues.

We are using:

- Centos 7
- Php 7.4
- MySQL 5.7

So many requests to this exact file causes cpu usage to raise :

```
<?php
// required headers
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods:POST");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, X-Requested-With");
include_once '../../fun/DBconfig.php';
include_once '../../classes/api.php';
$database = new DBconfig();
$con = $database->connect();
$api= new api($con);
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
date_default_timezone_set('Africa/Algiers');
$ops_arr=array();
$api->apikey=isset($data->apikey) ? $data->apikey : null;
    if(($api->testapi())>0){
        $sql="SELECT * FROM reservations WHERE statut = '".$data->state."' ORDER BY reservations.id DESC LIMIT $data->limit ";
        if ($s = mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
            while ($ruselt_category = mysqli_fetch_assoc($s)) { 
                extract($ruselt_category);
                $op_item=array(
                    "id"  => $ruselt_category["id"],
                    "id_rider"  => $ruselt_category["id_rider"],
                    "id_chauffeur"    => $ruselt_category["id_chauffeur"], 
                    "id_vehicle"    => $ruselt_category["id_vehicle"], // phone number
                    "id_payer"    => $ruselt_category["id_payer"], // password
                    "poit_start" =>$ruselt_category["poit_start"],
                    "poit_end" => $ruselt_category["poit_end"],
                    "prix_total" => $ruselt_category["prix_total"],
                    "date" => $ruselt_category["date"],
                    "statut" => $ruselt_category["statut"],
                    "raison" => $ruselt_category["raison"],
                    "rating_client" => $ruselt_category["rating_client"],
                    "feedback_client"  => $ruselt_category["feedback_client"],
                    "rating_driver"  => $ruselt_category["rating_driver"],
                    "feedback_driver"    => $ruselt_category["feedback_driver"], 
                    "distance"    => $ruselt_category["distance"], // phone number
                    "date_starting"    => $ruselt_category["date_starting"], // password
                    "date_arrival" =>$ruselt_category["date_arrival"],
                    "payment_method" => $ruselt_category["payment_method"],
                    "operation_number" => $ruselt_category["operation_number"],
                    "price_promo" => $ruselt_category["price_promo"],
                    "price_final" => $ruselt_category["price_final"],
                    "price_tva" => $ruselt_category["price_tva"],
                    "commisiont_driver" => $ruselt_category["commisiont_driver"],
                    "commisiont" => $ruselt_category["commisiont"],
                    "id_category" => $ruselt_category["id_category"],
                    );
                array_push($ops_arr, $op_item);  
            }
            mysqli_close($con);

            http_response_code(200);
            echo json_encode($ops_arr);
     
        }else{
            http_response_code(404);
            echo json_encode(
                array("message" => "No driver found.")
            );
            echo($s);
        }
    }else{
        http_response_code(500);
   }
?>
```

I have some diagnostics but I really don't know the exact problem
Here's some screenshots :

[image]

**Do I have to switch to Websockets or where is exactly the problem ?
Is Using SELECTS inside a main SELECT can cause this problem ?**

Comment: It looks like MySQL is the cause, not PHP. Make sure you have proper indexes on that table for this query

Comment: `extract($ruselt_category);` WHY?

Comment: Additional information request. 
Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
F) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes -
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: @HTMHell It was the indexes that caused the problem, thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I marked the external indexes(keys) in the table and It worked.